# Как стирать символы в поле ввода при использовании Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как удалить символы в поле, куда мне нужно запихнуть свою информацию.
К примеру. Открываем окно, с которого нужно отправить отчет на @mail, но при окрытии окна в поле mail уже прописан адрес другой почты например mail1@mail.ru, а роботу нужно стереть её и вписать туда mail2@mail.ru
как это реализовать подскажите.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://*********.ru")
driver.maximize_window()

mail = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'path')
mail.send_keys("mail2@mail")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732125/clear-text-from-textarea-with-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось вот таким образом:

```
for i in range(0, 19):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
    '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]
    /div[2]/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_id('foo').clear()
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно за ответ, но не работает. И так уже давно не используется, нужно так driver.find_element(By.ID, 'здесь путь') и 'foo' ты так путь id обозначил?

Comment: Да. Извини что не работает( Удалить?